# xsl transformation xmlwriter output only returning text C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xmlwriter

My output from this transformation only includes the text, but I want the HTML and text output. What do I need to change to do that?

I'm using VS 2010

current example output:

Jones Martin Kelley Marshall

Note I have this in the xsl too, but it wasn't showing in my code example:

```
 xsl:output
    standalone="no"
    method="xml"
    indent="yes"
    omit-xml-declaration="no"
    version="1.0"
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="/people">

      <div class="lastnames">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="lastname" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

C#:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

xslt.Load(xslPath);

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(outPath + 
                                          fileName + 
                                          "." +
                                            fileExt
                                         , xslt.OutputSettings))
{
    xslt.Transform(fileNode, null, writer);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please, provide the source XML document on which the transformation is applied. Without knowing it, it isn't possible to give you a meaningful answer. Please, edit the question and provide this important, missing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="people">
  <div class="lastnames">
   <ul>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="lastname">
  <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (non has been provided !!!):

```
<people>
 <lastname>Jones</lastname>
 <lastname>Martin</lastname>
 <lastname>Kelley</lastname>
 <lastname>Marshall</lastname>
</people>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<div class="lastnames">
  <ul>
    <li>Jones</li>
    <li>Martin</li>
    <li>Kelley</li>
    <li>Marshall</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**And it is displayed by the browser as expected:**

- Jones
- Martin
- Kelley
- Marshall

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the input data it's hard to be sure what's going wrong.  But first I'd suggest checking your `xsl:output` element; you say it's present in the input "but not showing in [the] code sample".  That in itself makes me suspicious.  The fact that when you do show it, it doesn't show up as an XML element makes me doubly suspicious.

They're not relevant to the question you actually asked, but a few other things strike me in reading your code:

The `xsl:output` you show uses `method="xml"`, but you're not producing XHTML; is there a reason you're not using `method="html"`?

Why are you disabling output escaping in the display of people's last names?  Do you expect input data to have less-than signs in people's names?  And if it does, do you want to create ill-formed output instead of putting the character data out?

The `xsl:for-each` in your single template is not doing any work (except to make the stylesheet complete silently without output if the root element is not named `people`).  Your stylesheet would be slightly more idiomatic if you replaced the template with

```
<xsl:template match="people">
  <div class="lastnames">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="lastname">
  <li>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, and i apologize for incomplete data.